# Insert a multiple choice in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I have to do is to make the user select some languages among those present on a page and get an **array or a string** that contains all the selected languages.
Do you know how can I do?
The string or array it will serve subsequently in a JavaScript method.

Comment: Please ask a proper question. Refer [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look at the edit please, I added the function for removing a unchecked language. Cheers.

Comment: @MrBuggy Thanks it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use some checkboxes and save the values in an array like this:

```js
var lang = [];


$('.cbLang').on('change', function() {
  this.checked ? lang.push(this.value) : removeLang(this.value);
  console.log(lang);
});

//REMOVE UNCHECKED LANGUAGE
function removeLang(removeLang){
    lang = jQuery.grep(lang, function(value) {
        return value != removeLang;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="English">English
<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="German">German
<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="French">French
```

**EDIT:** If you also need a way to remove it from the array, check the JQuery grep(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

**EDIT2:** I've added a function to remove a unchecked language from the array. This method calls, when a checkbox was unchecked and gives the value of the language as parameter. It should work like this.

Cheers

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Yes, I just solved the question, how to multiple select languages and add it to an array... I wrote also, if he also would to remove by unchecking, he can look at jQuery grep() and give him a template with a shortcut if... :) You can edit it if you want ;-) Cheers.

Comment: @Mohammad I've edited the code, with a new function for removing a unchecked language. Look at my edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var lang = [];


$('.cbLang').on('change', function() {
  ''
  this.checked ? lang.push(this.value) : removeLang(this.value);
  console.log(lang);
});
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="English">English
<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="German">German
<input class="cbLang" type="checkbox" value="French">French
```